# How to get from Amazon Elastic Transcoder the video duration?

Tags: amazon-web-services, video-processing

Im using this service but need to know the video length, but in the AWS docs there is no info or in the AWS response.

Answer (score 2):

The Get job method returns a response containing the duration of the output. See example below:

```
{
  "Job":{
  "Id":"Id that Elastic Transcoder assigned to the job",
  "Input":{
     "AspectRatio":"auto|1:1|4:3|3:2|16:9",
     "Container":"auto|3gp|asf|avi|divx|flv|mkv|mov|mp4|
        mpeg|mpeg-ps|mpeg-ts|mxf|ogg|vob|wav|webm",
     "FrameRate":"auto|10|15|23.97|24|25|29.97|30|60",
     "Interlaced":"auto|true|false",
     "Key":"name of the file to transcode",
     "Resolution":"auto"
  },
  "Output":{
     "Duration":"duration in seconds",
     "Height":"height in pixels",
     "Id":"sequential counter",
     "Key":"name of the transcoded file",
     "PresetId":"PresetId for the job",
     "Rotate":"auto|0|90|180|270",
     "SegmentDuration":"[1,60]",
     "Status":"Submitted|In Progress|Complete|Canceled|Error",
     "StatusDetail":"additional information about job status",
     "ThumbnailPattern":""|"pattern",
     "Width":"width in pixels"
  },
  "Outputs":[
     {
        "Duration":"duration in seconds",
        "Height":"height in pixels",
        "Id":"sequential counter",
        "Key":"name of the transcoded file",
        "PresetId":"PresetId for the job",
        "Rotate":"auto|0|90|180|270",
        "SegmentDuration":"[1,60]",
        "Status":"Submitted|In Progress|Complete|Canceled|Error",
        "StatusDetail":"additional information about job status",
        "ThumbnailPattern":""|"pattern",
        "Width":"width in pixels"
     },
     {...}
  ],
  "PipelineId":"Id of the pipeline that transcoded the job",
  "Playlists":[
     {
        "Format":"HLSv3",
        "Name":"name, no / character allowed", 
        "OutputKeys":[
           "Outputs:Key to include in this playlist",
           ...
        ]
     },
     {...}
  ],
  "Status":"Submitted|Progressing|Complete|Canceled|Error"
}
}
```

For more information see: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elastictranscoder/latest/developerguide/get-job.html

Comment: DetectedProperties]  and DurationMillis are empty for me...    any known reasons that createJob and readJob wouldn't return duration?